# Difference between H5_OpenGroup and H5Gcreate_f commands in fortran

Tags: fortran, hdf5

What is the difference between H5_OpenGroup and H5Gcreate_f commands in fortran while working with hdf data?

```
    CALL H5_OpenGroup(groupID1,'Schneide#'//TRIM(Make_String(Span%Flanke,'I2.2'))&
    &,groupID2, 'unknown', ierr)  
    IF (ierr > 0) THEN
      IF (ierr < 50) ierr = 302
      GOTO 999
    END IF
    IF (.NOT. existsS) THEN
        ! X
      CALL H5Gcreate_f(groupID2, 'X_1', groupID3, ierr) !
      IF (ierr > 0) THEN
        IF (ierr < 50) ierr = 303
        GOTO 999
      END IF
```

Answer (score 1):

The code sample that you post is not complete or useful.

Concerning the routines:

- `H5_OpenGroup` is not part of the Fortran API for HDF5. The routine that would correspond is [`h5gopen_f`](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5G.html#Group-Open) and opens an already existing group.
- [`H5Gcreate_f`](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/RM/RM_H5G.html#Group-Create) creates a new group within a HDF5 file.